# Getting an error while set up socket.io connection on jmeter

Tags: sockets, socket.io, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Required help to resolve following socket.io connection error.

Getting an error while setting up socket.io connection on jmeter.

want to set up a connection to the socket.

Is there any other prerequisite to run socket sample?

#### Actaul error

[image: Actaul error]

#### Socket.io sampler using web sampler plugin

[image: Socket.io sampler using web sampler plugin]

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case you're using an outdated WebSocket plugin, try switching to [JMeter WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers), these samplers are more advanced in terms of support of JMeter configuration elements like [SSL Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SSL_Manager), [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), etc.

Moreover, these plugins are being maintained and supported, i.e. last commit was made ~2 months ago while the plugin you're using seems to be abandoned for > 4 years.

Check out [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide) article or check [example test plans](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/295f0b0f9c002d935ec37b62839e26a40f02ecba/samples/?at=master) for if needed.

Comment: And even though the last commit was 2 months ago, i'm still maintaining it ;-)